# Angular RxJS Observable Filter on array of objects

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am new to Angular and Observable. I want to apply filter on array of objects. This is how my code looks. .

getReport() gets all reports.

```
 getReports(): Observable<IReport[]>  {
    console.log("in get Reports Service Call");
    return this._http.get<IReport[]>(this.URL)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log('All Data Retrieved - ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

I am trying to write another method that can filter based on report name and give me array of IReport. This is what I have now.

```
 getReportDetails(name : string) : Observable<IReport[]>
  {
    return this.getReports().pipe(
      map((reports : IReport[]) => reports.find(p => p.reportName === name))
    );
  }
```

I am getting error as

```
Type 'Observable<IReport>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<IReport[]>'.
```

Here is IReport  interface with 5 properties.

```
export interface IReport {
    date: Date;
    reportName: string;
    reportLink: string;
    reportStatus: string;
    region: string;
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks all.

Comment: Which method gives you the error when executed, getReports() or getReportDetails(name)?

Comment: getReportDetails(). Olivier helped me . I am good. Thanks

Comment: Oh.. great! I did not see

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it should be

```
map((reports : IReport[]) => reports.filter(p => p.reportName === name))
```

instead of

```
map((reports : IReport[]) => reports.find(p => p.reportName === name))
```

`find` will return the first `IReport` that matches the condition `p.reportName === name`

Answer (score 1):

Just try by changing `find` with `filter`, find is to get just one object, and filter is to get an array of objects

```
getReportDetails(name : string) : Observable<IReport[]>
  {
    return this.getReports().pipe(
      map((reports : IReport[]) => reports.filter(p => p.reportName === name))
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Even better solution for filtering returned data will be filter operator of rxjs

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html
And then you can just easily pipe it to your older observable and return observable of filtered data which you can subscribe on